# Apache rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am a rewrite newbie, I am wondering why this rewrite rule is not working, it ceases Apache from starting

`RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?/constant/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(.*)$ http://$2.domain.com/$1/$3  [R=301, NC]`

What this rule should do is URL refactoring, examples:

http://www.domain.com/controller/constant/variable/action should be redirected to
http://variable.domain.com/controller/action

and

http://www.domain.com/constant/variable should be redirected to
http://variable.domain.com

basically /constant/variable should be detected, inserted in the subdomain and then removed

Please help me in this subtle problem that I am facing.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "redirect", are you expecting a client-side redirect? That's not what rewrite rules are for.

Comment: What exactly is the error message of your Apache httpd?

Comment: Error : Syntax error in the configuration file. when I comment this line it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^constant/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ http://$2.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/constant/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(.*)$ http://$2.domain.com/$1/$3 [R=301,NC]
```

Also note that the flags must not contain any whitespace: `[R=301, NC]` is invalid syntax but `[R=301,NC]` is valid syntax.